# Call a C# dll from C++ (MSVC compiler)

Tags: c#, c++, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have a C# dll, and I need to call some of its functions from my C++ program (native C++, not C++/CLI).

What is the recommended way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Another way (also outlined in the article linked by Matten I believe) is to write the wrapper dll in C++/CLI.

You write a regular C++ class with DLL exports:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef CSCLIWRAPPER_EXPORTS
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else 
#define DLLAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class DLLAPI CsCliWrapper
{
private:
    void *wrap;

public:
    CsCliWrapper();
    virtual ~CsCliWrapper();
};
```

reference the managed dll in the project, and use it in the implementation:

```
#include "CsCliWrapper.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

CsCliWrapper::CsCliWrapper()
{
    CsPlugin^ obj = gcnew CsPlugin();

    wrap = GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(obj)).ToPointer();
}

CsCliWrapper::~CsCliWrapper()
{
    GCHandle h = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(IntPtr(wrap));
    h.Free();
}
```

Note however that this approach is not portable, at the moment there are no compilers supporting C++/CLI on linux or OSX.

Comment: Not sure which answer to accept, as all are viable solutions. Can you mention the other 2 solutions, so you're answer is complete, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is by creating C# COM server, and then calling it's functions from a C++ COM client, as outlined in MSDN's [COM Interop tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645738%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to host a CLR in the unmanaged process, an example is outlined in [the linked article with examples](http://1code.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Invoke%20.NET%20Assembly%20from%20Native%20C%2b%2b#HostCLR). This is the solution we prefer because we don't need no COM interop. Another example is given at [this MSDN page](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0).